# Use the Instagram Graph API without a business manager account

Tags: api, instagram

I am trying to use the Instagram Graph API, but when creating my app, I didn't set a Business Manager account. It looks like I cannot use the API as https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/accounts? doesn't return anything.
I have a Business Page on Facebook but it is not verified so I cannot use it, and it is totally unrelated to my app. How should I do it?
Thanks,
Gigi

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm trying to use the Insta Graph API as well, but confused on if I need to submit my app for review first because I don't have an app yet!